# Get tag attribute in Onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div style='padding:10px;border:1px solid #888;width:150px;' id='btnTest' data-id='1'>
    <label>
      <input type='checkbox' name='test1' />
      TEST1
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type='checkbox' name='test2' />
      TEST2
    </label>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
  $('#btnTest').click(function(e){
    console.log($(e.target).attr('data-id'));
  })
});
</script>
```

In that test code, if I click the label area, I can not get the data-id value,

Is there any way I can get the data-id even I click the other element in that DIV tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $(this).attr('data-id');
```

e.target refers to the element clicked, this to the element where the handler is binded.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'this':

```
$(function() {
  $('#btnTest').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('data-id'));
  })
});
```

However if you want the checkbox's 'name':
Do:

```
$(function() {
  $('#btnTest label input').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can simply do:

```
$(function() {
  $('#btnTest').click(function(e){
    console.log($(e.target).parent('#btnTest').attr('data-id'));
  })
});
```